# Detecting nodes in xml as2

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

So i have this code so far

```
var my_xml = new XML();
my_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
my_xml.onLoad = onXMLLoaded;

function reloadXML(){ 
my_xml.load("direktno.xml");
}
my_xml.load("direktno.xml");
function onXMLLoaded() { 
 if (my_xml.childNodes) {
 _root.main.ma4.minutegoal1.text = my_xml.firstChild
 }

 if (my_xml.childNodes[1]) {

    _root.main.navigator._visible = true;
} else {

    _root.main.navigator._visible = false;
}
}
```

Basically I'm, loading data from XML file in SWF file. Here is the XML:

```
<game>
<minute>67</minute>
<score1>1</score1>
<score2>3</score2>
</game>

<game>
<minute>67</minute>
<score1>1</score1>
<score2>3</score2>
</game>
```

So now there are two childNodes  `<game>` As you can see I'm checking for `(my_xml.childNodes[1])` and in my case there is, so the `navigator` is shown. But after it's been shown I have to make a button inside and when it's been pressed to load the content from second `childNode` to `_root.main.ma4.minutegoal1.text`

Answer (score 0):

In Actionscript 2, you need to use the [Xpath API](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=459947). If you want to be able to use dot notation as shown, which is called e4x, you need to use Actionscript 3.